# HerokuにRubyのデータをデプロイした時のRouting Errorについて質問です

Tags: ruby, heroku

rubyデータをcloud9からherokuにデプロイしようとしてます。 
URLを確認したら 
https://sakuhin.herokuapp.com/ 
見れない状態でした。

下記のようにターミナル上でheroku logsで原因を見たら多分ルーティングエラーのようでした。 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s687/sh/7eae22fd-4447-4b46-bd36-dbb7ee48c3b9/3486c077dad2a8144c48ecd56a592894

おそらくpublicにindex.htmlを置くか / を解決するコントローラを置く設定をする必要があると思われるのですた肝心の方法がよく分からない状態です。

現在のconfig/routes.rbの表記は下記のようになります。ここをどのような表記に変更したらindexが見れるようになるのでしょうか。 
 get "static_pages/index" 
 post "static_pages/index" 
 get "static_pages/date" 
 post "static_pages/date" 
 get "static_pages/q1" 
 get "static_pages/qw2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root 'static_pages/index'
```

を追加すれば表示できると思います。

`root`が指定されてないならローカル環境でも表示されてないでしょうし、できればHerokuに上げる前にローカル環境で確認された方がいいですよ。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
route.rbに
root 'static_pages/index'を置いてアップし直して時間を置いたらデータが表示されました。
ただ/assets/type.jpgなどの画像データのほうが見れない状態で、今調べ中になります。